# ES6 Promises return before catch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

**How can I achieve, that the caller of saveThings() get's a precise error description (A or B). Currently, my rejection of type A get's caught in the catch() clause, thus the caller always ends up with message B...**

```
saveThings() {
    return api.post(endpoint, data)
    .then( response => {
        if ( !response )
            reject({message: 'error of type A - faulty response'});

        resolve('all went well');
    })
    .catch( err => {
        throw new Error('error of type B - call failed');
    });
}
```

Comment: What are `reject` and `resolve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it depends on when and therefore what you catch

```
saveThings() {
    return api.post(endpoint, data)
        .catch(err => {
            throw new Error('error of type B - call failed');
        })
        .then( response => {
            if ( !response )
                throw new Error('error of type A - faulty response');

            return 'all went well';
        });
}
```

or

```
saveThings() {
    return api.post(endpoint, data)
        .then( response => {
            if ( !response )
                throw new Error('error of type A - faulty response');

            return 'all went well';
        }, err => {
            throw new Error('error of type B - call failed');
        });
}
```

wich are pretty much equivalent. Only the first one creates an intermediate Promise, after the `catch`, wich the second one doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, also to @Bergi. The first solution of turning things around is so simple... too many trees, didn't see the forrest. 

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to [use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572):

```
return api.post(endpoint, data).then(response => {
    if (!response)
        throw {message: 'error of type A - faulty response'};
    return 'all went well';
}, err => {
    throw new Error('error of type B - call failed');
});
```